# ng new command response with available commands

Tags: angular-cli

`ng new` command is responding with available `ng` commands, so that not able create new projects

[image]

```
**C:\MEAN>ng new my-app

Available Commands:
  add Adds support for an external library to your project.
  analytics Configures the gathering of Angular CLI usage metrics. See https://angular.io/cli/usage-analytics-gathering.
  build (b) Compiles an Angular app into an output directory named dist/ at the given output path. Must be executed from within a workspace directory.
  deploy Invokes the deploy builder for a specified project or for the default project in the workspace.
  config Retrieves or sets Angular configuration values in the angular.json file for the workspace.
  doc (d) Opens the official Angular documentation (angular.io) in a browser, and searches for a given keyword.
  e2e (e) Builds and serves an Angular app, then runs end-to-end tests.
  extract-i18n (i18n-extract, xi18n) Extracts i18n messages from source code.
  generate (g) Generates and/or modifies files based on a schematic.
  help Lists available commands and their short descriptions.
  lint (l) Runs linting tools on Angular app code in a given project folder.
  new (n) Creates a new workspace and an initial Angular application.
  run Runs an Architect target with an optional custom builder configuration defined in your project.
  serve (s) Builds and serves your app, rebuilding on file changes.
  test (t) Runs unit tests in a project.
  update Updates your application and its dependencies. See https://update.angular.io/
  version (v) Outputs Angular CLI version.
For more detailed help run "ng [command name] --help"
C:\MEAN>**
```